# Is it possible to have a subform that changes based on a indirectly related form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, relationship

I have a database structure in this format: [Relationship Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87MZo.png)

I have worked out how to attach a subform which displays children of a particular record:

[Ex 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nypQz.png)

[Ex 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpuwx.png)

However, I can't seem to find a way of having a subform listing the related grandchildren of a record. For example, all formulations that reference a particular material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bind your subform directly to the table, but bind it to a query instead.

Handle the Child - Grandchild relation in the query, and the parent-child relation in the form, like you're already familiar with.